# GridView with responsive FooTable plugin breaks with paging

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I am trying to implement a responsive design in my gridview using the jQuery FooTable plugin, but seem to be getting caught up when trying to implement paging into the gridview. The style seems to break, and try to force a regular gridview when I click on the second page. It looks completely fine when it initially loads. How can I solve this?

My code for the gridview is as follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GV_ProgramByKeyword" runat="server" Visible="false" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ODS_ProgramByKeyword" CssClass="footable" GridLines="None">
   <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="ProgramName" HeaderText="Program" SortExpression="ProgramName" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="CredentialType" HeaderText="Credential" SortExpression="CredentialType" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryName" HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="CategoryName" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryID" HeaderText="CategoryID" SortExpression="CategoryID" Visible="False" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryDescription" HeaderText="CategoryDescription" SortExpression="CategoryDescription" Visible="False" />
   </Columns>
   <EmptyDataTemplate>
      No data available now
   </EmptyDataTemplate>
   <PagerStyle CssClass="gridview-paging" />
</asp:GridView>
```

And this is where I populate the grid and adjust the expandable headings in code behind, set off on a button click:

```
protected void LinkBtn_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Attribute to show the Plus Minus Button.
        GV_ProgramByKeyword.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Attributes["data-class"] = "expand";

        //Attribute to hide column in Phone.
        GV_ProgramByKeyword.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
        GV_ProgramByKeyword.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";

        //Adds THEAD and TBODY to GridView.
        GV_ProgramByKeyword.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;

        GV_ProgramByKeyword.Visible = true;
        SearchKeywordHeader.Visible = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same issue and I have fixed it by changing the line below line

```
 GV_ProgramByKeyword.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
```

You need to do below:

Step 1:
Create jscript function on the page:

```
    <script>
    function fixGridView(tableEl) {
        var jTbl = $(tableEl);

        if (jTbl.find("tbody>tr>th").length > 0) {
            jTbl.find("tbody").before("<thead><tr></tr></thead>");
            jTbl.find("thead tr").append(jTbl.find("th"));
            jTbl.find("tbody tr:first").remove();
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Step 2: Change below line:

```
GV_ProgramByKeyword.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
```

to :

`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", string.Format("fixGridView({0});", GV_ProgramByKeyword.ClientID),true)`;

[Reference](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2010/Nov/18/Adding-proper-THEAD-sections-to-a-GridView)